# Watch Extension iCloud capabilites, which target?

Tags: xcode, icloud

I added Core Data with iCloud support to my watch extension, but it's not syncing with the phone (phone and iPad do sync). I added the iCloud and notification capabilities to the My App Watch Extension target, but on Xcode, you don't seem able to add it to the My App Watch target? Could this be my issue, that the iCloud capability is only added to the one target on the watch instead than on both?

[image]

[image: Watch showing no capabilites]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try add to `...Watch`, you can't do it.

You should add it to `...Watch Extension`.

Comment: Thanks. That’s what I thought, but I am so frustrated with it not syncing that I wanted to make sure